# Angular JS - Get the component controller instance manuallly

Tags: angularjs

In Angular JS I would want to get a component controller instance manually, that ideally is achieved through the `require` binding in component. I have a requirement where in I am outside the Angular JS component environment and I cannot use `require`.

```
// Sample require binding  
module.component('superHeros', {
  template: `
  <h2>
    Super Heros Component
  </h2>
  `,
  require: {
    parentCtrl: '^heroList'
  },
  controller: superHerosControler
});
```

Though I thought this could be achieved with `$injector` of angular but does not seem to work (throws Unknown provider).

So I want to do this

```
require: {
        parentCtrl: '^heroList'
      }
```

like this `this.requiredController = $injector.get(<componentName>);`

I understand that this works perfectly for Services or factories. Is there a way to achieve this or a workaround that can essentially get me an component controller instance ?

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uzOgHXWzpJTotZkI?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can't you use some sort of scope binding for this ? I mean bind to your component the other component scope that you want to access?

Looks a little hard to find your requested workaround since the component/controllers etc are not persistent in the application like Services/Factories you also mentioned. So for me looks like a custom binding could help. But I need to see your component hierarchy better.

Comment: @jaderanderson, thanks for the reply. I think you are correct on that I still need to give a thought on this. Can you help me here, so if I am right when I say, technically, when I run $compile('<element-name></element-name>'), when I execute this, at this point the angular js component is created and all the code in the controller of that component are executed. So basically every time the component is rendered on the screen, the same happens.